# Grouped Stacked Bar Plot in R from Table Columns

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want to generate a plot looking like this:

[image]

Could you give me a hint how top achieve that? I startet with:

```
  T1 <- c(23.2,34.5,76.3,65.8,12.6)
  T2 <- c(15.6,12.4,21.8,20,5.2)
  T3 <- c(15.6,12.4,21.8,20,5.2)
  A <- gl(5,1,5,labels=c("Mähen","Wenden","Schwaden","Pressen","Abtransport"))

  data <- cbind(T1,T2,T3)
  rownames(data) <- levels(A)
  barplot(x1,names.arg=levels(A))
  barplot(x3,names.arg=levels(A))
  #barplot(t(data),beside=F, ylim=c(0,100),legend.text=colnames(data),
  barplot(t(data),beside=F, legend.text=colnames(data),
  col=c("grey50","grey80"),ylab="Arbeitszeitbedarf [h/ha]")
```

Comment: Presumably "x3" was intended to be "T3"? And can you explain what arrangement of data you had in mind the plot suggests only two groups but you have three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat like you requested... except for all the missing values that you do not provide.

```
 png('rplot2.png'); par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)  )
data <- cbind('T1 - Grundzeit'=T1,'T2 - Hilfszeit'=T2)
   rownames(data) <- levels(A)
   barplot(t(data),beside=F, legend.text=colnames(data),
   col=c("grey50","grey80"),ylab="Arbeitszeitbedarf [h/ha]", 
   args.legend=list(inset=4,x=7,y=70))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I solved my problem partially by using: 
abline () to add lines and space=rep() to add space between bars.
I solved the problem with the ylim with ylim=max(rowSums()) of the datamatrix.
Further edits I did with GIMP